# Why are my img and text not aligning next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is how it looks, the uppest part is how it should look. (Sorry, Its written in Dutch)]I'm building a website, but my image won't appear next to my text. I don't get this, because above it is the same design, and it works there.

Note: I do not use div's that much, because I have learned at school that its not that necessary

This part is working

```
<div class="presentatie">

            <img src="assets/IMG/presentatie.jpg" alt="Jan-Joost presentatie" class="img--presentation">

            <div class="tekst--rood">
                <p class="tekst--groter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br></p>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br><br>
                <p class="tekst--presentatie">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
                    <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a class="click" href="Link">Click</a>
                </p>
            </div>
```

This part is not working

```
               <div class="tekst--rood1">
                <p class="tekst--groter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
                <p class="tekst--workshop">
                    MLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    <br>
                    De mogenlijkheden bespreken? <a class="click" href="Link">Click</a>
                </p>
        </div>

        <img src="assets/img/workshop.jpg" alt="Jan-Joost workshop" class="img--workshop">
```

This is the css, as you can see the "inline-block" has been put in at every class.
(of both parts)

```
    .img--presentation{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 514px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.tekst--rood{
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.tekst--presentatie{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.click{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tekst--groter{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.img--workshop{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 505px;
    margin-left: 850px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tekst--workshop{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tekst--rood1{
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `margin-left: 850px` causes the image to wrap to the next line in viewports that are less than 1670px wide. I suggest that you learn about [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: Yep, thats it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .img--presentation{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 514px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.tekst--rood{
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.tekst--presentatie{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.click{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tekst--groter{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.img--workshop{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 505px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tekst--workshop{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tekst--rood1{
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```